# Magento 2: Checking an Admin User's Access Level

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, acl

In Magento 2, you can create access control rules for admin users at

```
System -> User Roles
```

As a backend Magento programmer, how can you check which rules the currently logged in admin user has assigned?  i.e. which object(s) do you need to inject, and which methods do you need to call on them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session` should give you the current user that is an instance of `\Magento\User\Model\User`.
From this user, `getRole` should give you the role that is an instance of `\Magento\Authorization\Model\Role`.
`\Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\AclRetriever` contains a method `getAllowedResourcesByRole` that receives a parameter `$rid` (role id).
I didn't test this, but I think you can combine the 2 above into this:

```
protected $aclRetriever;
protected $authSession;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Authorization\Model\Acl\AclRetriever $aclRetriever,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession, 
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->aclRetriever = $aclRetriever;
    $this->authSession = $authSession;
    ....
}
```

then have a method like this:

```
public function getAllowedResources()
{
    $user = $this->authSession->getUser();
    $role = $user->getRole();
    $resources = $this->aclRetriever->getAllowedResourcesByRole($role->getId());
    return $resources;
}
```

if the current user has access everywhere you should get an array with only one element `Magento_Backend::all`.
If you have custom access for the current user you should get an array with elements that look like this `[Namespace]_[Module]::[resource]_[subresource]`. Basically, the `id` attributes of the `resource` tags you have in the `acl.xml` files.

Answer (score 2):

Use Magento\Framework\Authorization\PolicyInterface

Please find the example of usage at \Magento\Framework\Authorization::isAllowed

```
    $resourceString = "[Namespace]_[Module]::[resource]_[subresource]"; 
    //example "Magento_Backend::admin"
    $roleId = $user->getAclRole();
    return $this->aclPolicy->isAllowed($roleId, $resourceString);
```

`$user` can be obtained by injecting `\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session` and calling `getUser()` method in it.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the accepted answer's statements "I didn't test this", and "should", let me put in some test results here.

The `$resources` variable will be an array of strings. I made a slightly different function myself:

```
public function getIsAllowed($resource) { // like a string, e.g. "Magento_Backend::cache" for Cache Management
    $role = $this->authSession->getUser()->getRole();
    $resources = $this->aclRetriever->getAllowedResourcesByRole($role->getId());
    return in_array($resource, $resources) or in_array("Magento_Backend::all", $resources);
}
```

which allows for easier checks - as you'll probably want to do a membership check with a special case for Magento_Backend::all anyway.

Constructing the block like the accepted answer will work straight away.